# Do multiprogramming Operating systems have preemption? what about multitasking operation systems?

Tags: operating-system

So i know that in multiprogramming O.S can switch to another job when a process requires I/Q, but is this considered preemption ? Do multiprogramming Operating systems have preemption? what about multitasking Operating  systems?

Comment: Can someone explain to me whats up with people downvoting this? i didn't find this question being asked in this website at all? or people of this website are too expert for this kind of rookie questions?

Comment: It's too broad for this site. We aren't a site for general operating system architecture questions.

Comment: For me, the question is pretty clear and specific. As for asking about both multiprogramming and multitasking OS, this is probably for better understanding the answer.

Comment: I have trouble with better understanding the question.  Can you give currently available examples of such OS, for clarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So i know that in multiprogramming O.S can switch to another job when a process requires I/Q, but is this considered preemption ?

No, the process normally yields.

> Do multiprogramming Operating systems have preemption?

Generally but not always.

> what about multitasking Operating systems?

Generally but not always.